# drawing list of Chevron Diagrams (TIKZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-path

I am currently trying to draw a list of chevron diagrams using TIKZ. The result should look something like this:

| [image: preferred result] |
| --- |
| *preferred result* |

Currently I am so far with my code that I am using Paths. However, these are lined up horizontally (see figure). Is there any way to tell that these should be listed vertically?

| [image: my Result] |
| --- |
| *current result* |

**my code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,
    align=left,font=\sffamily,on chain,minimum height=2em,
    inner xsep=1em},start chain=going right,node distance=1ex]
   \path node[signal from=nowhere]{3 traces\\25.0 \% of the log} node[fill=violet]{A} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=red]{D} ;
   \path node[signal from=nowhere]{3 traces\\25.0 \% of the log} node[fill=violet]{A} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=red]{D} ;
   \path node[signal from=nowhere]{3 traces\\25.0 \% of the log} node[fill=violet]{A} node[fill=red]{D} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=red]{D} ;
   \path node[signal from=nowhere]{3 traces\\25.0 \% of the log} node[fill=violet]{A} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=red]{D} node[fill=magenta]{E};
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I think the solution is not that hard, however, so far I have not found a way to set that paths should not be appended in the horizontal.

Thanks a lot for all the answers

Comment: please post complete compileable examples rather than snippets.  It makes it much easier to help if we can simply cut and paste your example.

Comment: @Thruston, thanks I have updated my question with using the complete code

Comment: I think [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540281/15036) about chains of chains is similar...  does it help?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if I understand you question correctly. But why don´t you put your arrows in different `\tikzpicture` enviroments.

Is this your expected result?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,
    align=left,font=\sffamily,on chain,minimum height=2em,
    inner xsep=1em},start chain=going right,node distance=1ex]
   \path node[signal from=nowhere]{3 traces\\25.0 \% of the log} node[fill=violet]{A} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=red]{D} ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,
        align=left,font=\sffamily,on chain,minimum height=2em,
        inner xsep=1em},start chain=going right,node distance=1ex]
    \path node[signal from=nowhere]{3 traces\\25.0 \% of the log} node[fill=violet]{A} node[fill=magenta]{E} node[fill=red]{D} node[fill=magenta]{E};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, all your nodes are on one chain that's `going right`. A `\path` doesn't start a new chain.

However, the `chains` library has support for branches, thus, we use one chain that's going below (this only works good because all your nodes on the left has the same horizontal dimension), and for each of those nodes we start a branch going to the right where we put all the other nodes on.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Sig/.style={
    shape = signal, signal from = west, signal to = east,
    minimum height = 2em, inner xsep = 1em, Sig #1/.try},
  Desc/.style={align = left, shape = signal, minimum height = 2em},
  /utils/temp/.style args={#1:#2}{Sig #1/.style={fill={#2}}},
  /utils/temp/.list = {A:violet, D:red, E:magenta},
  start chain = going below,
  node distance = 1ex
]
\sffamily
\foreach \traces/\percent/\List in {
  3/25.0/{A, E, E, D},
  3/25.0/{A, E, D},
  3/25.0/{A, D, E, D},
  3/25.0/{A, E, D, E}}
\node[Desc, on chain] {\traces\ traces \\ \percent\,\% of the log}
  [start branch = branch going right]
  node foreach \t in \List [Sig = \t, on chain] {\t}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]